# custom point to point path with bezier curve animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna create a moving car object that animates from point-A to point-B, point-B to point-C, and point-C to point-D.  I'm using the "jQuery.Path.js" with bezier curve function but it only has 2 points to setup (start & end).  How can I add 2 more points in between?? please help!

here's the original js page:  [JQUERY PATH BEZIER CURVE GENERATOR](http://jqbezier.ericlesch.com/)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.path.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function animate(){
      var path = {
                start: {
                  x: 1200,
                  y: 445,
                },
                second: {
                  x: 890,
                  y: 520,
                },
                third: {
                  x: 650,
                  y: 600,
                  angle: 20,
                  length: 0.2   
                },
                end: {
                  x: -100,
                  y: 470,
                }
              };
      $('.car').animate(
          {
            path : new $.path.bezier(path)
          },
          20000,
          animate
        );
    }
    animate();
</script>
```

Comment: Ive checked source, its young lib (version 0.1). This lib is accepting only `start` and `end` point. Last commit have 5 years ago, so im afraid you can't add more points. Find another library

Comment: thanks for the response~ I've found a similar article here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612942/how-to-animate-an-image-along-a-path-with-bezier-curves?rq=1 and I think maybe I should use GSAP to make the animation, but it seems a little difficult to me tho.